# Plesk Nginx Wordpress Permanent links 404 Not Found nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks, plesk

Tired of searching on the web without results so I end up here asking for help.

I am using Plesk to manage my server I activated PHP-FPM for Nginx and wanted start
Processing PHP by Nginx so I set up these options (picture below):

**IMAGE** : http://goo.gl/U8Ul0a

The Index page is working well because I add it in the setting as you can see on the 
   image The probléme is the Permanent link any link i click on i get 
   **404 Not Found Nginx**
   When I turn off Wordpress permalinks All work fine and when I switch back only 
   the home page work.

Any help pls !

Comment: have you tried rewrite rule for Nginx instead Apache ?

Comment: well no coz i dont know :p if u can give me a step by step pls !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guy's I m pleased to tell you that i found better solution to fix this 404 Nginx error.

You just need to download this extension : htaccess to nginx

And go to your domaine -> Web Server Settings -> click on Show .htaccess converter -> Copy what u already have on your .htaccess in your ftp root -> then click 
convert to nginx.

So it will convert it and past it in the Additional nginx directives field then save it and "Ta Da !!!!!"

It s gonna be working Inchaalah without any security issue. our freind UFHH01 know what i m talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Well, thank you guys for your help!
By searching more in SO and some external forums, I was able to find a solution.

Here are the steps how to add custom include in Nginx virtual host config:

```
mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain

cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
```

and edit the location code you have already with the following code:

```
location ~ /$ { index index.php index.cgi index.pl index.html index.xhtml index.htm index.shtml; try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; }

/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all # to apply new configuration for all domains
```

Answer (score 1):

You must just insert in the "Additional nginx directives":

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

Do not insert the `"location / {" en de final "}"`

Answer (score 0):

If your wordpress is at the root level this is all you should need to do for your location / block

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: can u please tell me on which file i should add this code ?

Comment: I've never used the plesk interface but from your picture I would try the bottom under Additional nginx configuration

Comment: When i try add it in this field i get :
Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /var/www/vhosts/system/fondationmjid.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:1 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: It looks like you'll need to edit the main plesk template as they discuss on this forum.  http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/nginx-configuration-for-vhosts.260814/